# PHP+MySQL getting and putting data to database

Tags: php, mysql

How can I put and read data from PHP and MySQL? I tried the following:

```
$pwdcrypt = SHA1($pwd);
echo "Now we put some data to the database!";
$userregisterquery="INSERT INTO user (email, password) VALUES ('$email', '$pwdcrypt')";
echo $userregisterquery;
mysqli_query($link, $userregisterquery);

$usergetdataquery="SELECT email, password FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
echo $usergetdataquery.'</br>'; 
$result =  mysqli_query($link, $usergetdataquery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);

// get the user_id
$useridquery="SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE email = '$email'";
echo $useridquery.'</br>'; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $useridquery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
echo "the result is:".print_r($row);
mysqli_close($link);
```

It outputs, for example:

```
Now we put some data to the database!INSERT INTO user (email, password) VALUES ('fdjisadds@as.com', 'cf860129c95e6afcdb9f9a390354915cde81c40c')We put email: fdjisadds@as.com and password: cf860129c95e6afcdb9f9a390354915cde81c40c to the database.SELECT email, password FROM user WHERE email='fdjisadds@as.com'We get: 1
```

As I checked that id=1, I found that it is some other user I put there via SQL-terminal and no email fdjisadds@as.com.

Comment: Your output has nothing to do with your code. Please provide the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($link, $useridquery)` fetches an array of results. `print_r($row)` is then printing that array to the output stream and returns `true` which is concatenated to the string as `1`.

From the PHP manual

> If given a string, integer or float, the value itself will be printed. If given an array, values will be presented in a format that shows keys and elements. Similar notation is used for objects.
>   When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the return value is TRUE.

So try this instead:

```
// This would concatenate the print_r's result to the string
echo "the result is:".print_r($row, true);

// Or better yet, use the following
echo "the result is:".$row[0]
```

**EDIT**
Regarding the questionaire's last comment:

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Be aware, though, that based on the limited insight you provided, this could break some other logic of yours.

Comment: Console says I haven't put data to my database. I think there is something wrong in my insert query.

Comment: Please check whether the user.id column is AI (autoindexed), otherwise your insertions will definetly fail (granted user.id is a NOT NULL column).

Comment: I found an auto_incremented option but how to set an autoindexed option on?